# Paragraph indent, both \indent and \par, not working

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Preamble. I use Win 8 Pro x64, MiKTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter latest version.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\onehalfspacing
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}
\setotherlanguages{english, russian}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsection}
\numberwithin{table}{subsection}
\pgfplotsset{pa/.append style={axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left, xlabel={$r; \cdot 10^7 m$}, ylabel={$F_{pa}; \cdot 10^8 N$}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
```

Piece working as needed:

```
\begin{center}
\noindent \large{\textsc{University \\
Department\\
Faculty}}

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent \Large{name \\
\textbf{Topic} \\
Study}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\begin{FlushRight}
\noindent \large{Work advisor: \\
Professor } \end{FlushRight} \bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{center}
\noindent \large{\textsc{City, Year}}
\end{center}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

Here I make `titlepage` according to the asked style.
Then I go for my abstract. And there are no paragraph indents, but I need one at the first line (after `section`, and I tried to use both `\par` and `\indent` for two different paragraphs in that piece of text. Also, not a single intent working in anywhere further in document.

```
\section*{Abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
\\ \indent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\newpage
```

It should have three indents, but has none.

Looking through existing similar questions didn't bring me any sort of solution either.
Also, I've put my build log on pastebin - http://pastebin.com/0EiP5BKw

Comment: In order to end a paragraph, don't do ``\\ \indent``, but rather leave an empty line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have loaded the package `ragged2e` with the `document` option, that kills indents and typesets the document in raggedright fashion, which I don't think is what you want.

I've also made some changes to your input, so that it's more easily manageable. Note that commands such as `\Large` *don't* take an argument, but set their action to continue until countermanded by another command or the end of the group where they have been issued.

Note also that a paragraph is ended by simply leaving an empty line in the source code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath} % must go before fontspec

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[
  top=2.5cm,
  left=3cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
  \usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
  \pgfplotsset{
    pa/.append style={
      axis x line=bottom, 
      axis y line=left,
      xlabel={$r; \cdot 10^7 m$},
      ylabel={$F_{pa}; \cdot 10^8 N$}
    }
  }

%% Fonts and languages
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
]{Times New Roman}

\setdefaultlanguage{latvian}
\setotherlanguages{english, russian}

%% Misc settings
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {1em}
  {}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsection}
\numberwithin{table}{subsection}

\onehalfspacing

\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

{\large\scshape
  University \\
  Department \\
  Faculty
\par}

\vspace*{\fill}

{\Large
  name
\par}

{\Large\bfseries
  Topic
\par}

{\Large
  Study
\par}

\vspace*{\fill}

\raggedleft

{\large
  Work advisor: \\
  Professor
\par}

\vspace{\fill}

\centering

{\large\scshape
  City, Year
\par}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section*{Abstrakts}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @kalstrams I appreciate your edit to remove possibly sensitive data, not the one changing my style of typing. Not a big deal, anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just was not sure about your style of typing so I, hopefully understandably, was not able to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `\parindent` to 0pt. Please set, e.g., `\parindent30pt` before your Abstract.

As far as I understand, you need not paragraphs, but paragraph indentations.

Comment: Yes, I need paragraph indentation. As for the `parindent`, isn't it set to `24pt` in preamble ? `\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{24pt}`

Comment: Nevermind. I do not really understand the difference of what I had and what you said, but adding `\parindent30pt` fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Probably it is changed somewhere. But `\parindent24pt` should indent your abstract,

Comment: The way `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e]` "kills indents" is it  changes `\parindent` to `\RaggedRightParindent` (default 0pt) at `\begin{document}`. Any change to `\parindent` before that will not stick. One must either set `\parindent` *after* `\begin{document}` or set `\RaggedRightParindent` in the preamble.